# Directed Graph Equivalence Class

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following conversion involving directed graphs.

To convert from $\mathcal{G}$ to $\mathcal{G}^u$ (they have the same number of vertices):

1. $V_i \rightarrow V_j$ in $\mathcal{G}^u$ iff $\exists$ a directed sequence from $V_i$ to $V_j$ of length $u$ in $\mathcal{G}$
2. $V_i \leftrightarrow V_j$ in $\mathcal{G}^u$ iff $\exists$ a pair of directed sequences forming a fork in $\mathcal{G}$:

   $ \pi_1$:$ V_c \rightarrow ... \rightarrow V_i$

   $ \pi_2$:$ V_c \rightarrow ... \rightarrow V_j$

where length($\pi_1$)=length($\pi_2$) $\leq u$ and $V_c$ is some vertex in $\mathcal{G}$

Note that $\mathcal{G}= \mathcal{G}^1$. No bidirected edges are allowed in $\mathcal{G}^1$. Also note that if $u \rightarrow v$ and $v \rightarrow u$, this is not the same as $u \leftrightarrow v$. The former is two single directed edges whereas the latter is one bidirected edge. So, for example, it can be the case that there exists a bidirected edge between $u$ and $v$: $u \leftrightarrow v$ and only a single directed edge from $u$ to $v$: $u \rightarrow v$ all in the same graph.

One pattern I have noticed is that although we can extend $u$ indefinitely for $\mathcal{G}$, there exists a $u_{MAX}$ such that for any $u \geq u_{MAX}$, $\mathcal{G}^{u}$ is a graph in $\{\mathcal{G}^1,\mathcal{G}^2,\mathcal{G}^3,...,\mathcal{G}^{u_{MAX}}\}$. (Sort of makes me think of a group but I wouldn't know what the operator is)

The equivalence class of a graph $\mathcal{H}$  consists of all graphs $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{G}^u = \mathcal{H}$ where $u$ is ANY undersampling rate.

Given an $\mathcal{H}$ and a $\mathcal{G'}$ that belongs in the equivalence class of $\mathcal{H}$, is it possible to determine ALL elements of this equivlance class efficiently?

Is there perhaps some obvious property I am missing between members of the same equivalence class? I have tried determining by brute force all elements of an equivalence class for a given H (small number of nodes obviously) and haven't found any sort of pattern involving in degree or out degree between the members.

Comment: Take a look at monoids in the context of finite automata, perhaps you will find something useful.

Comment: I know that a monoid satisfies associativity and has an identity element but when you say "in the context of finite automata" I am a little lost. Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Your graphs are quite similar to finite automata, and there is an algebraic theory about monoids which describe how finite automata match words. Simirarly you could define function $f_G : 2^V \to 2^V$ described as $v \in f(A) \iff \exists u \in A.\ (u,v) \in E(G)$ and take the monoid generated by repeated composition, or perhaps the monoid that considers all the possible graphs at once. I don't know if this is a good idea, but there are certainly some connections.